# How to check if an array is one of the elements in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I am trying to assert that an array of string elements is one of the elements of a 2-dimensional array using the standard **Collection.isIn** matcher provided with Hamcrest library. Unfortunately receiving the following assertion exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: one of {["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B", "C"]}
   but: was ["A", "B", "C"]
```

**Code:**

```
String[][] expected = new String[][] { { "A", "B", "C" }, { "A", "B", "C" } };
String[] actual = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

assertThat(actual, isIn(expected));
```

Can I validate using hamcrest in such a manner? Or do I need to create my own matcher for the given scenario?

Comment: I made the question easier to read by substituting shorter strings. It does not affect the question or answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `Object.equals()` doesn't do what you might expect when the objects are arrays. As you probably already know, you have to use `Arrays.equals()` -- but Hamcrest `isIn()` does not allow for this.

Probably the simplest solution is to convert to `List` even if only for the test -- because `List.equals()` works as Hamcrest expects:

```
...
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIn.in;
...

String[][] expected = new String[][] { { "A", "B", "C" }, { "A", "B", "C" } };

Object[] expectedLists = Arrays.stream(expected).map(Arrays::asList).toArray();

String[] actual = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

assertThat(Arrays.asList(actual), is(in(expectedLists)));
```

Comment: thanks for providing the list based solution alternative with hamcrest.

Answer (score 1):

Your array may contain the same content as the array in `expected`, but it is not the same object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would be better off using `List<>` instead of arrays.

Secondly, yes, if you insist on using arrays, you will need to write your own 'array-contains-element' function.  You can implement this function using a loop over the major dimension of the array, invoking the `Arrays.equals()` method to compare the contents of two one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue is because the method compares objects, and not contents. Basically, even though both have the same content, they are not the same object. [See here in the docs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html#matches(java.lang.Object))

Do this instead:

`String[] actual = new String[]{"A1 C1 E1 F1 J1", "A1 C1 E1 F1 K1", "A1 B1 G1 H1"};
String[][] expected = new String[][]{actual, {"A1 C1 E1 F1 J1", "A1 C1 E1 F1 K1", "A1 B1 G1 H1"}};`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with collection.IsIn in your context, is that your elements of your list is an array and it will use the Array#equals to compare each element.

More specifically

```
// It will print false, because Array.equals check the reference 
// of objects, not the content
System.out.println(actual.equals(new String[]{"A1 C1 E1 F1 J1", "A1 C1 E1 F1 K1", "A1 B1 G1 H1"}));
```

So I suggest creating a custom matcher that uses Arrays.equals from java. It will compare the content of arrays for you. Something like code below:

```
public boolean matches(Object item) {
    final String[] actualStringArray = (String [])item;

    List<String[]> listOfStringArrays = Arrays.asList(expectedStringMatrix);

    for (String[] stringArray : listOfStringArrays) {
        // Arrays.equals to compare the contents of two array!
        if (Arrays.equals(stringArray, actualStringArray)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```